# How to slide in text and push another text to the right (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the `>` move in from the side and push the "Lorem" to the right. I'm trying to make it within my CSS.

[image: images]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element and `transition: max-width`

```css
* {
  line-height: 1;
}
span:before {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width .5s;
  content: '>';
  display: inline-block;
}
span:hover:before {
  max-width: 2em;
}
span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like : 
HTML CODE :

```
<p id ="lo"> > Lorem </p> 
<span id="ipsum"> Ipsum </span>
```

CSS :

```
#lo { 
margin-left : 10px;
}
```